# Arranging of elements in xml with the use of jaxb/java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I rearrange my xml elements from:

```
- <course>
  - <CourseType>
    - <GroupIndex>
         <index>1</index> 
         <professor>James</professor> 
      </GroupIndex>
      <classType>Lecture</classType> 
    </CourseType>
  <courseCode>3000</courseCode> 
 </course>
```

To:

```
- <course>
    <courseCode>3000</courseCode>
  - <CourseType>
      <classType>Lecture</classType>
    - <GroupIndex>
         <index>1</index> 
         <professor>James</professor> 
      </GroupIndex> 
    </CourseType> 
 </course>
```

It's about how to arrange them such that elements that cant be expanded will always be above those that can be expanded.

I'm using JAXB marshalling in java to convert my objects to produce the xml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a proporder in the class you are unmarshalling should help with this issue

e.g.

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "courseCode",
        "CourseType"
    })
```

note: when using a propOrder all elements in the object must be added to the propOrder.

Comment: I would also like to direct you to a blog from @BlaiseDoughan http://blog.bdoughan.com/, he and his blog have been very useful in JaxB related issues.

Comment: Thanks alot! Solved my problem and that's a good blog. Thanks again for the recommendation.